# EXCEL TO GET profit type

Tags: excel

i have following excel

```
column A    COLUMN B    COLUMN C    COLUMN D    COLUMN E            COLUMN H    COLUMN I    COLUMN J
NAME    Type1   Type2   DATE       PROFIT           NAME    TYPE1   TYPE2
XX      900      PE     1/20/2016   11500            XX     950      CE
XX      900      CE     1/20/2016   1000             ACC    SORRY   SORRY
XX      950      CE     1/20/2016   1000                    
XX      950      CE     1/20/2016   26000                   
XX      950      PE     1/14/2016   2750                    
ACC     1140     CE     1/20/2016   1500                    
ACC     1160     CE     1/20/2016   1500                    
ACC     1160    PE      1/18/2016   2625                    
ACC     1160    PE      1/19/2016   3000                    
ACC         1160    PE          1/20/2016   3000
```

OTHER ROWS and new  names ADDED DAILY

i want to write an excel formula to get the type 1 and type2 in column I, J against names ,such that for a particular name contents of column D and E contents are maximum simultaneously. eg for name XX maximum of column D is 26000 and column E is 01/20/2016 so the contents of this row is printed in column I,J. FOR NAME ACC max type 2 is 2750 which is occuring at date 01/14/2016 which is not maximum so it gives output as "sorry". cna you please help me to write the formula

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to provide a more clear description of what you need and *what you have tried to meet that need*. We can then help better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array formula will do the trick:

In I2 put:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$11,MATCH(1,IF($D$2:$D$11=MAX(IF($H2=$A$2:$A$11,$D$2:$D$11)),IF($E$2:$E$11=MAX(IF($H2=$A$2:$A$11,$E$2:$E$11)),1,0),0),0)),"Sorry")
```

This is an array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So put in I2 then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Then you can copy over and down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note: your example does not match your verbal requirements.  ACC Maximums are the last line of data.

So just to prove that the formula works I changed the last line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner for the help.Taking a cue from the formula given by you i have used =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,IF(D:D=MAX(IF($H3=A:A,D:D)),IF(E:E=MAX(IF($H3=A:A,E:E)),1,0),0),0)),"Sorry") in the column I2 as my data consists of more than 20000 rows. However i am facing a problem. If i am testing individual name containing less data then output is correct but on excel worksheet having all the data having 20000 rows, its giving errors at many places.I donno where the problem is. Can you please help further

Comment: Sir, I have suggestion my formula calculates all the rows in millions, can we use =MATCH(REPT("z",255),A:A) in the index function to limit the number of calculations?

Comment: One without the data it is hard to determine what is wrong. Two that formula finds the last cell with words. You want `=MATCH(1e+99,A:A)`  . three this is a new question   this question has been answered and should be accepted as such.